# What to use for C# SlimDX Game UI

Tags: c#, user-interface, slimdx

I am currently developing a 3d game using C#/SlimDX (The target is Direct3D 9). I've been looking for a suitable Game UI toolkit for a while, but I was unable to make up my mind.

The Game UI will be for a roleplaying game, so it'll be fairly complex and will involve quite a few controls (text boxes, inventory grids, list boxes, select boxes, scrollable areas, etc.).

I previously (When i was still using C++/OpenGL) looked at [GameSWF](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html) and very much liked the idea, but for my current game it's out of the question.

Does anyone know a good GUI toolkit for use with SlimDX?

I would be especially interested in using WPF/Silverlight for this, since there are good IDEs available for both. But a quick google search didn't reveal any information on embedding these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WPF (but not Silverlight) for this.

The way to go about this is to use SlimDX in conjunction with [D3DImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.d3dimage.aspx).  You then let WPF handle all of your final composition, including overlaying the WPF UI over the top of your SlimDX scene.

SlimDX basically just renders to a brush in this situation, which can be used on any WPF element.  (This doesn't work for Silverlight, as Sliverlight doesn't support D3DImage.)

Comment: Hi,
is it still possible to use FullScreen Direct3D?
And what is the performance hit for the main scene for this?

Comment: Well, it does work, fairly well. There is a performance hit, but the main thing is that you have to let WPF handle the compositing, which means you're working at WPF's framerate instead of yours - kind of like having vsync on.  The biggest hit comes from having to have D3D_MULTITHREADED on and working in a window instead of direct, though, in terms of your D3D calls.  That being said, we've been doing this, and been very happy.  You can make a window fullscreen in WPF fairly easily, though.  Unfortunately, this is the only way to directly use WPF for your UI.

Comment: Without this type of approach, you'll have airspace issues with WPF.